# Access private data .env file in gitlab CI django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am stuck in a issue I dont want to commit my .env file on gitlab, but during CI I need that values for database configuration like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

while my file in actual

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": config("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT", cast=int),

    }
}
```

so what is possible way to assign these values to **run tests.py** in CI gitlab

Comment: Alternate way is setting up [Gitlab CI/CD environment variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)

Comment: @SouravAtta yes but I am getting these variables by doing this  `config("DB_USER")` on live server   from my `.env` file  but gitlab variable can be accessed only by   `os.getenv('DB_USER')`   so  how I can merge both at same time ?

Answer (score 0):

A few options here. The most obvious would be to use GitLab's [CI/CD environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-variable-in-the-ui). You can also create files in the job this way, too, not just env variables.

You could have a template `.env` file an edit it using `sed` to inject the values from the CI/CD env variables (if you don't want to create a .env file type variable).

Another way would be to store the configuration values somewhere secure like Hasicorp Vault and [retrieve secrets from vault in the job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/). A similar thing could be achieved with storing the secrets anywhere, doesn't have to be Vault. You would store the secret to *access* the vault in masked CI/CD variables.